# Get package use flags

Tags: gentoo, portage

How can I get list of specific package's use flags?

So, there are at least 2 ways to do that:

- `emerge -pv $PACKAGENAME`
- `equery uses $PACKAGENAME`

But these commands returns to many noisy information. All I want is simple list like

```
  useflag1
  useflag2
  useflag3
```

without any words about are they set or not or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach (for `portage`, for example):

```
#> grep --perl-regexp --only-matching "(?<=IUSE=\").*(?=\")" `equery which portage`
build doc epydoc +ipc linguas_pl pypy2_0 python2 python3 selinux xattr
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe the output of `equery uses` it will strip any "noise" to keep only the USE flags and a `+` or a `-` whether it is enabled or not.

Here is your command:

`$ equery u $PKGNAME | cut -c 2-`

Comment: Funtoo here -- a working example: `equery u virtualbox-bin | cut -c 1-`